# Translation of "Please tell me how to get to your house."?

Tags: translation

I can only get as far as 请告诉我怎么.

Answer (score 4):

In a less westernised way, you may say,

"請問你的家怎麼走?"

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%90%E5%8C%96%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87

Comment: Of course there are multiple ways to ask this simple question which is normally spoken. It also boils down to how well you are acquainted with the listener, which would govern the degree of formality of the words, phrases used. It can range from 你家在哪儿, (where is your home), to a breathless 20 worded dissertation.

Answer (score 2):

```
                    [Please] [tell] [me] [how to] [get to] [your] [house].
simplified Chinese     请      告诉  我     怎么      去      你的   住所（房子，居住的地方，或家）
traditional Chinese    請      告訴  我     怎麼      去      你的   住所（房子，居住的地方，或家）
```

In Pinyin（拼音）:

```
请       告     诉     我     怎     么     去    你     的     住     所
qing(3)  gao(4) su(4) wo(3)  zen(3) me(1)  qu(4) ni(3)  de(1) zhu(4) suo(3)
```

In English, I think `house` is not `home`, and it's the same in case of Chinese.

The above answer is in Mandarin not Cantonese or any other Chinese dialect.

Comment: 所 is pronounced as "suo(3)"

Comment: @nanoix9, thx, I have modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

请告诉我怎么到你的房子。
家是home, house is referred to with the word 房子

Answer (score 1):

去你家怎么走？

well, do I really need 30 characters.............

Answer (score 0):

请告诉我怎么去你住的地方house here means where you are living in now.maybe you live alone without your family here.you can not translate house into “家”.家 means home .“住的地方”means the place you living in.

Answer (score 0):

What's the matter of these simple question?

> Please give me your address
>
> 请给我你的地址。

If you want to be more specific en-route.

> How to get to your place if I start from location X
>
> 如果从 X 点出发， 要如何走才能到你家。

HOWEVER， if you really ask something ambiguous such as  "Please tell me how to get to your house? "

> Walk ！
>
> 用脚走 ！

Answer (score -1):

> 请告诉我怎么去你家

最简明扼要的应该是这个意思了。
The most concise should be the meaning of the.